# How to relay System.Net.ConnectStream to another request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have two cloud provider with their client SDKs say SDK1 and SDK2. And I wanted to copy one file from one cloud to another cloud storage. These SDKs have upload and download APIs like this:

`Response uploadAsync(Uri uploadLocation, Stream fileStream);
 Stream downloadAsync(Uri downloadLocation);`

Earlier I was copying downloaded `Stream` to `MemoryStream` and passing it to upload API. And it was working but obviously, it will load entire file to memory which is not good.

I cannot directly pass downloaded `Stream` to upload API as somewhere it's checking `Length` of `Stream` and `System.Net.ConnectStream` being non-seekable throws `Exception`.

Any pointer on how can we use the downloaded `Stream` (which is of Type `System.Net.ConnectStream`) in upload API without actually storing entire file?